# How to close modal dialog when file download completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal dialog which contain form and hidden iframe to which form is submitted. The result of submission is file to download. 
I need to close modal dialog as soon as download dialog is opened i.e. file is ready.
I was trying to catch 'onreadystatechange' event of iframe, but after submit call changing state to 'complete' it does not trigger 'onreadystatechange' event.

Eventually, i use window.setInterval which monitoring readyState of iframe and close modal dialog when its state == 'complete'.

the solution that using window.setInterval seems not professional to me and I am looking for better solution, I saw solution with cookies but I can't use cookies in my application.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download

Comment: @yan Did you ever see a FF solution for the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong or unprofessional in using `window.setInterval()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response!!!!!
Is javascript you provided should be in iframe body?

Comment: I have modified the answer. You should accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Hi, i don't want to call parent method my iframe is hidden and doesn't load page it used to submit the form without refresh the page.
I use it to download file and want to close modal dialog as file is downloaded. Sorry for misunderstanding and thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function Close_Popup() {
        $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
        $('#div_Popup1').modal('hide');
        $(".modal-backdrop fade in").remove();
    }
```

Call this function on OnClientClick="Close_div_Popup1_Popup();"